# Python MacOs Webbrowser deletes URL Parameters in Local Links

Tags: python, macos, python-webbrowser

I have a problem using webbrowser in python on MacOs. I am very confused about this, because in ubuntu this runs great.

Following code snippet opens a browser windows with test.html, but the parameter q=1 is missing.
If i open a link starting with "https://...?q=1" this works also fine.
Could it be, that MacOs implementation of webbrowser deletes the URL parameters for links starting with "file:///"?

Any suggestions of a platform independent solution for opening a local html file with URL parameters?

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new("file:///Users/myname/test.html?q=1")
```

Thanks a lot and best regards
Felix

Comment: Maybe `python -m http.server`?

Comment: Good one! This works of course. But I guess this could not be the best solution. I thought Python is more platform independent :(